# How can I check the version of libssh2 git was compiled with?

Tags: git

I recently received a notice from a cloud hosting provider that they will no longer be accepting Git connections from clients that use versions of libssh2 below 1.7.0. We have a couple of build tools that use Git, and I'm trying to figure out how I can check what version of this library they were compiled with. I've come up short with my previous searches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In most/all? (Linux) systems, `git` (as in the command line tool) isn't compiled against any SSH library. Instead, it uses an SSH client (like `ssh` from `openssh-clients`) for its transport (this usually means `git` is completely unrelated to `libssh2`).

However, there might be situations where this isn't the case. In that situation

- check the dependencies of your tool
- check with `ldd /path/to/your/gittool` to see what dynamic libraries the binary is linked against
- If your tool is very strange and statically links `libssh2`, the most reliable way to identify this would be the source code

Comment: There are third party git libraries that use libssh2, but the original git itself does not.